# Vb.net Listview: change a label text in Edit mode

Tags: listview, gridview, controls, edit

I am using a listview to display data from database. In Edit mode, there is a save button to update data. I put a label beside the save button and want it display the update status. The save button raises a ItemCommand event, and in this event, I set the label.text to be the status. But the label never shows up. Is there any way to achieve this?

Front end:

```
<EditItemTemplate> 
   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" runat="server" CommandName="Save" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("FileId") %>'>Save</asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=''  ></asp:Label>
```

Backend:

```
If e.CommandName.ToLower.Equals("save") Then
    Dim lblStatus As Label = CType(listView1.EditItem.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
    lblStatus.text= "Status"
End if
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This Questions seems to Cover the same issue, may be this helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273194/vb-net-datagrid-set-edititemtemplate-field-visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273194/vb-net-datagrid-set-edititemtemplate-field-visible)

Comment: I justed wanted to ask if you could solve the porblem or if you still need some support?

Comment: i the given solution didnt help, and you have a better one please share with the community, or accept a give answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably **the order where the events fire and you are loading the listview**.

Try debugging(stepping through or oldfashion print lines ;-) ) the Code and you will notice that first the Command Event is execute and than som listview Data binding stuff is going to happen. Checkout a brief summary of the page life cycle **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/444310/ASP-NET-Page-Life-Cycle-Events)** 
i think if you change the order of the calls your problem should be solved.

i hope this helps.

**edit**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If (Not IsPostBack) Then
   ' This code Just runs only on the initial load of the Page
   ' here set datasource and do databinding
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I stepped through the codes, and like you said, the Command Event fires first and then data bind second. The data binding event erases the Label1.text. If I set the Label1.text in data binding event, how can I set the text to success or fail based on the status of the Save event?

Comment: You would would have to load the list view page Load or Preload or before. Like this the Control Event overrides the default-values. The exact Order of the events fired you can find in the link i posted in my answer.

Comment: or only data binding the listview if it `Not IsPostBack` see my edit.